# How to handle highcharts-custom-events in highcharts-ng?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts-ng

I've installed **highcharts-custom-events** from the Highcharts plugins, https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

I wanted to make the labels in the Highcharts chart to be clickable and run a function when clicked but this returns this error

[image]

I do know that the click is being recognized but the isNumber function that is in customEvents.js is not existing. Does the highcharts-custom-events plugin have to be modified to get it to work with highcharts-ng? If so, how could I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the high-charts plugin page [as accessed from the link above], click on the demo link.. you should be directed to a JS fiddle page.

Ensure that you have added the external resources mentioned in the Left hand side page of the JS fiddle page as accessed above.